Post-apocalyptic movie with two siblings
Here is a picture from the movie:
https://twitter.com/FilmDevourSFF/status/1213471900418134017
It appears to be about two siblings who have to fight in an apocalyptic world, but I can't find the name of it.

I could be wrong, but a new account as of today asking as their first question the name of a movie that's clearly stated in the reference link smacks of advertising. I'm flagging as spam.

Hello! I'm sorry if I made it seem that way. You can try and search the movie by the name listed ('A kingdom we call home', shown by Dean Conway), and let me know if you find anything, because I couldn't. I guess I should have better asked for the name of the actors depicted in the picture rather than the name of the movie.

you could message the Film Devour Short Film Festival and ask them. The odds are good they'd either give you the info or put you in touch with the production team. Or you could visit a Facebook post about the short and post the question. Or you might ask Katie Haughian, who lists the short in her credits. A Google search revealed a number of direct-ask sources that made more sense than here.

Katie Haughian is the actress in the picture. When finished in 2019 she was only 13 years old.

As per the Tweet, it appears to be called A kingdom we call home, shown by Dean Conway at the Film Devour Short Film Festival.
I can't find much information beyond that, and no guarantee that it was released any more widely.

I tried to search for further information, but I still couldn't find anything...no release date, no actors, no actual plot. It's just that the actors seem quite popular to me (although I can't put my finger on it) and the shot appears to be from more than just a short movie which has never been widely released. But thank you for your help!
